# How to get values from json nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
{
  "Petition to file": [
    {
      "description": "fileing description",
      "period": "30 days",
      "fees": "500"
    }
  ],
  "Appearing before inspection": [
    {
      "description": "Appearence Description",
      "period": "10 days",
      "fees": "1500"
    }
  ],
  "Passing orders for a recording of statements": [
    {
      "description": "passing order description",
      "period": "50 days",
      "fees": "1000"
    }
  ],
  "Hearing of petition": [
    {
      "description": "Hearing of petition description",
      "period": "55 days",
      "fees": "2000"
    }
  ],
  "Decree of petition": [
    {
      "description": "decreeof description",
      "period": "70 days",
      "fees": "5000"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to get the values of nested child headings. It is dynamic content .Also i need to fetch the values of nested objects that is period,fess,description . I'm using typescript program that is  in angular cli

Comment: did you attempt anything at all ?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: The point is the title(example:Petition to file) of nested object will be dynamic by server response .

Comment: use Object.keys to get the dynamic keys and map them into an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is complete working example [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmbxqh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), Your main logic of traversing dynamic object entries is...

```
ngOnInit(){
    Object.keys(this.datafromDatabase).forEach(data =>{ 
         this.datafromDatabase[data].map(key =>{
           this.data.push(key)
         });
    })
}
```

Your Template file is...

```
<div *ngFor="let key of data">
    {{key.description}}
</div>
<div>
     {{data |json}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var something = consts['Petition to file'];
```

usually thats the way to get the values inside keys

so now the new variable `something` =

```
[
    {
      "description": "fileing description",
      "period": "30 days",
      "fees": "500"
    }
  ]
```

now if u want `description`

```
var descriptionVariable = consts['description'];
```

so descriptionVariabe's value is `fileing description`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let list = {
  "Petition to file": [
    {
      "description": "fileing description",
      "period": "30 days",
      "fees": "500"
    }
  ],
  "Appearing before inspection": [
    {
      "description": "Appearence Description",
      "period": "10 days",
      "fees": "1500"
    }
  ],
  "Passing orders for a recording of statements": [
    {
      "description": "passing order description",
      "period": "50 days",
      "fees": "1000"
    }
  ],
  "Hearing of petition": [
    {
      "description": "Hearing of petition description",
      "period": "55 days",
      "fees": "2000"
    }
  ],
  "Decree of petition": [
    {
      "description": "decreeof description",
      "period": "70 days",
      "fees": "5000"
    }
  ]
}


for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(list)) {
  console.log(key);
 console.log(value);
}
```

Use `Object.entries`